# AS3 Anonymous class passed as variable to function

Tags: actionscript-3

In c++ if I have a function that takes a class I have defined elsewhere as a parameter like so:

```
void moveto(CPoint2D point) { ... }
```

I can invoke it and pass along data to it like this:

```
moveto(CPoint2D(0,0));
```

basically creating the object and invoking it's constructor to be passed to the function

Is there an equivalent to this in AS3?

if I have a function like this:

```
function initialize(min:Point, max:Point): void { ... }
```

how do I do something along the lines of :

```
initialize(Point(0,0), Point(10,10))
```

This throws an error im assuming because it thinks I want to cast something to a point and the notation I found earlier to do something similar only seemed to work if using the basic Object class. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make new objects (not classes) using `new`:

```
var min:Point = new Point(0, 0);
var max:Point = new Point(10, 10);
initialize(min, max);
```

To pass anonymously-created objects (i.e. skip the variables), you pass in the entire `new` expressions directly as arguments, like this:

```
initialize(new Point(0, 0), new Point(10, 10));
```